# Double Click Publisher 2 leaderboard banner in one page

Tags: javascript, html, ads, google-dfp

Hi I try to put the 2 leaderboard in one page but its shows only one leaderboard.

This is my Header code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
(function() {
var gads = document.createElement('script');
gads.async = true;
gads.type = 'text/javascript';
var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + 
'//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
googletag.defineSlot('/179670003/Leaderboard', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-   ad-1363780690140-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.enableServices();
});
</script>
```

This is my Document Body

```
<!-- Leaderboard --> 
<div id='div-gpt-ad-1363780690140-0' style='width:728px; height:90px;'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1363780690140-0'); });
</script>
</div>
<!-- Leaderboard -->
<div id='div-gpt-ad-1363780690140-0' style='width:728px; height:90px;'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1363780690140-0'); });
</script>
</div>
```

will it possible to add 2 leaderboard banner in one page?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a second ad unit called Leaderboard2. You can only display an adunit once per page. Then you could create a placement that includes both of your Leaderboard ad units and target all of your Leaderboard line items at the placement, they will then intelligently be shared between the two Leaderboard ad units.